# covert string into date time format in field ledObj.Scheduled_Time__c= csvRecordData[10];

Tags: datetime, csv

this value is in my csv 5/4/2016 15:00:00 and when i upload csv its not save into field.

```
public class importDataFromCSVController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<lead> leadlist{get;set;}
  public importDataFromCSVController(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    leadlist = New List<lead>(); 
  }

  public void importCSVFile(){

           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 

           for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
               lead ledObj =  New lead();
               string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
               ledObj.LastName= csvRecordData[0] ;             
               ledObj.Experience__c= csvRecordData[1];
               ledObj.Current_CTC__c=  decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[2]);
               ledObj.Expected_CTC__c= decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]);   
               ledObj.Company= csvRecordData[4]; 
               ledObj.Location__c= csvRecordData[5];
               ledObj.Phone= csvRecordData[6];
               ledObj.Email= csvRecordData[7];
               ledObj.Notice_Period__c= csvRecordData[8];
               ledObj.Certified__c= csvRecordData[9];
               ledObj.Scheduled_Time__c= csvRecordData[10];
               ledObj.Interested__c= csvRecordData[11];
               ledObj.Scheduled_By__c= csvRecordData[12];


               leadlist.add(ledObj );   
           }
           try{
        insert leadlist;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        }  
  }
}
```

Comment: is Scheduled_Time__c a String or a Date field? If it is a Date field then you need to convert csvRecordData[10] to a Date before storing it in Scheduled_Time__c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your Field Scheduled_Time__c is a Datetime field then you need to convert the String from your csv to a DateTime object.

Do the following in order to convert the String into a Datetime Object:

```
ledObj.Scheduled_Time__c= Datetime.parse(csvRecordData[10]);
```